# Will html image paths still work after precompile?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, path

I'm building a Rails app, but I'm using a plugin in which I have to render my images using only html.

Since I haven't deployed yet, all my images are in `RAILS_ROOT/app/assets/images/`, so to render an image I have to write the following code:

```
<img src="/assets/image.jpg">
```

But when I'm ready to deploy to the web and I perform a precompile, all my images are supposedly going to be moved to my `public` folder. Will the html still work to link to the image, or will I have to change to link to a different path?

The plugin I'm using is Typeahead:

**application.html.erb***

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      //....
      $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        maxLength: 5,
        displayKey: function(thing) {
          return "<div  class='typeahead'><img src='" + thing.image_url + "'></div>";
        },
        source: bloodhound.ttAdapter(),
      });
  </script>
```

**things_controller.rb**

```
def typeahead
  #render json: Thing.where(name: params[:query])
  q = params[:query]
  render json: Thing.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{q}%")
end
```

*Thing.image_tag is currently set to `"/assets/[image.jpg]"`, except for each thing it's adjusted with the proper file name.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use image_tag? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: My  plugin doesn't recognize Rails, so I have to use html.

Comment: What plugin are you using? Can you provide a code gist?

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: @Kuldeep Rails 4.0.10

Answer (score 1):

Not only are they going to be in the `public` folder, but they'll be renamed to include the fingerprint.

You **must** use the Rails helpers for all assets, [see how to here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) and read the rest of the guide while you're at it :)

Comment: I'm using a plugin that uses json, so it doesn't recognize Rails. Do you mean that the html paths will be renamed to link to the public folder? What is a fingerprint?

Comment: I have no idea what a plugin that uses json has to do with anything. Please read the guide I linked you to, the explanation is much longer than can fit here.

Comment: I did, but that section only talks about how to render images using Rails. My plugin returns data using json, so I can't embed am image with Rails, because it doesn't recognize the language. Therefore, I have to use html.

Comment: @smathy, wow! You "must" use the Rails helpers? While it is certainly preferred you can bypass the asset pipeline in a couple of different ways.  The most obvious way being to just put static assets directly into the public folder.

Comment: @JoeMorano - you said that you're entering `<img src="/assets/image.jpg">` - which is not JSON, so perhaps your question needs some editing. Even so, using the helpers are the way to create URLs or paths to the assets in `app/assets`

Comment: @bigtunacan, yes, strictly speaking an "asset" (generic meaning) could be anywhere, I'm obviously talking about what the OP is asking about, which are the assets in `app/assets` - ie. "assets" in the context of Rails.

Comment: @smathy, `must` just seemed inappropriate since it is more of a `should` with certain exceptions.  Either way; I agree there is too little information in the question here to provide an answer.  @JoeMorano asks about creating an `<img>` tag one minute, but needing JSON the next, and these two things don't really jive.  More clarification is needed.

Comment: I disagree. Within the context of the question, the title of which specifically asks about the precompile step when releasing to production, and the body of which is asking about assets in the asset pipeline, you **must** use the asset helpers.

Comment: @bigtunacan @smathy I added my plugin code above. And apparently I don't know a whole lot about json. I thought the `return` line was rendering the results with json, but maybe not. Either way, `image_tag` doesn't work in that line. Html `img` does work, but I just want to make sure I have the correct value of `Thing.image_url` when I deploy my app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `non-stupid-digest-assets` gem as it copies all your assets(mentioned in assets precompile list) in `public/assets` folder and then you need not to change your code before/after compiling.To install, you just need to add it into your Gemfile.

`gem 'non-stupid-digest-assets'`

I hope it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Joe, my suggestion would be to create a directory in your public folder to house your images, instead us using the app/assets directory.  The public folder will allow the assets to not be altered by the rails pipeline, and you can link to them reliably using any external services that need the images.

As stated in [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline):

> Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under
>   public will be served as static files by the application or web server
>   when config.serve_static_files is set to true. You should use
>   app/assets for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they
>   are served.

So you would need to add this line in `config/application.rb`

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

As described in [Rails general configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing your `image_url` in your model, and that's not working because assets don't have fixed URLs in Rails. I would override the getter in your model to use the `asset_path` helper, so it translates the path when that attribute is read (e.g., when the JSON is generated).

Something like:

```
# thing.rb

[...]

def image_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(read_attribute(:image_url))
end

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

But it isn't that big a deal to remedy. Just move the images you need to reference with html into your Public folder. Then you can simply reference them with this code:

```
<img src="/image_name.image_type">
```

and the html will link to the correct path, both before and after precompile. So you don't have to change any code before you deploy.

**BTW**: I assume `image_tag` and `image_url` are the same column and you just made a mistake in one of the two times you mentioned it. If that's the case, then don't forget to change it to simply "/[image.jpg]".

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, it's just `image_tag`. Well that's kind of annoying but thanks for the answer.